# Is there any way to finish Activities automatically in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

first I will give a brief explanation about my program.

I am trying to build a Point Of Sales System in Android Studio, Currently I have 4 Activities which are **Login Activities**, **Register Activities**, **Forgot Password Activities**, and **Main Activities**.

Basically when you use `Finish()` in each activities, it will dismiss all operation on the activity, in other words you can't go back to the previous activity after the `Intent`.

I am wondering instead to put `Finish()` on each activities, can I do that to all my activities automatically?

Comment: I don't understand. How would the system know when an activity should be finished? This is normally associated with some user action.

Comment: @Piyush Thanks bro, but what I actually need is like to clear the stack of previous activities not all activities include that i'm currently in.

Comment: @Henry that's it, what I actually needed was something like clear the previous stack of activities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by keeping no histroy of back stack. Try below code.

```
Intent i = new Intent("your intent stuff"); 
i.setFlags(i.getFlags() | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
startActivity(i)
```

**or second way of doing the same** You can do this by adding flag in your manifest as well. Add below code in your manifest file.

```
android:noHistory="true"
```

You need to add above tag in application tag.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I see that you came to the same conclusion, thanks for your help. hmm is No History mean that it will not save it to the stack?

Comment: I see, really appreciate it bro, I hope I can give you my best regards.

Answer (score 1):

Just add flags into the intent before starting activity

> in Kotlin

```
val intent = Intent(this, NewActivity::class.java)
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)
startActivity(intent)
```

> in java

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, NewActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
```

Comment: Thanks, you are great to provide also the Kotlin, currently i'm not using it though. but still thanks for your help.

Comment: please accept and upvote, if you found answer helpful

Comment: of course since it solve my problem, it is just unfortunately It said vote by a user under 15 Rep will not change the publicy score. so sorry.

Comment: @SerafinWilliam for solving your 15 Rep matter, let me help you :)

Comment: i see you accepted other answer even after my answer work for you and was accepted

Comment: I'm not sure, it can only give one answer so to make it fair I will only give my upvote to you. so sorry here, i will give another on your another question when i'm able to upvote @RahulKhurana

Answer (score 0):

You can add this.And it's clear all previous activity and data.

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | 
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I add Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP in my list.You can check.So it's not may be similar.

Comment: adding Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP doesn't make any difference. because other 2 flags have done the task i.e. clear all the previous activities from stack